# Can't get 1 second on a ATMega168 timer

Tags: arduino-mega, timers

```
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  OCR1B =  0xFF00;
  TCCR1A = (1<<WGM10) ;
  TCCR1B = (1<<CS12) | (1<<CS10);; //set the pre-scalar as 1024
  TIMSK1 = (1 << OCIE1A);
```

This doesn't produce a 1 second timer, it seems to produce a 0.5 second timer? I've calculated it based on the fact that I'm using the internal 8MHz internal clock on the chip.

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: OK, I truly don't understand anything about timers, this is the first time I've ever tried one. I tried to figure it out using this tutorial: https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/AVR_Timer_programming
All the examples are related to 16MHz, and the calculations are confusing to me because of the switch between formats which I don't know. After a lot of googling I figure out what I should be pushing into the calculator is ((8000000/1024)*1)-1) = 7811.5 (Although what I do with this number is a mystery) I think I'm supposed to subtract this from 65536 or perhaps some other randomly generated number. You then take the result of this and turn it into the hexadecimal equivalent of a boy band name, like E17 use lots of arrows to point away from things that look like the names of radio stations, WGM10 (bringing you all the hits of the 80's and 90's)

I apologize for the sarcasm, I couldn't help myself. What I really need to know is:

1. How do you actually calculate a 1-second delay one timer 1 when you are using the 8MHz internal clock of the ATMega168PA ? What are the numbers to type into a calculator?
2. Which switches should I be setting? I thought these were the correct ones.
3. What does OCIE1A stand for, can't find it in the documentation or the tutorial, only in the example code?

I should probably also add all I am doing is incrementing a count and displaying the count in my loop.

```
ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{
  count++;
}
```

Comment: Re “_I tried to figure it out using this tutorial_”: This tutorial suggests periodically resetting the timer. This should not be done: it is a sure way of missing ticks. I suggest looking for a better tutorial. And then, **this is mandatory**, reading the datasheet (just the chapter on Timer 1).

Comment: `TCCR1B = (1<<WGM10);` doesn't do anything, because on the next line, you overwrite TCCR1B. Secondly, for the /1024 prescaler, you need to set both the CS12 **and** the CS10 bit. So `TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12) | (1<<CS10);`. I don't understand how your code is actually giving you a .5Hz signal.

Comment: Sorry, I was meeting around when editing the question. I've pasted directly from the code.

Answer (score 2):

In normal mode, the timer counts from 0 to 65535 (0xffff), and then
rolls over back to zero. With a prescaler set to 1024, the period is
then 1024 × 65536 = 67108864 CPU cycles.

If you want to control the timer's period, you should not use normal
mode, but rather CTC mode (for “clear timer on compare match”). In this
mode, it counts from 0 to the value stored in OCR1A, and then starts
back at zero. With the same prescaler, the period is then
1024 × (OCR1A + 1) CPU cycles.

Comment: I have added the line: TCCR1A= (1<<WGM12) | (1<<WGM13); But this appears to have no effect.

Comment: @RickDearman: 1. If you select mode 12 (`_BV(WGM12)|_BV(WGM13)`), then the TOP of the count is selected by ICR1. Use mode 4 if you want TOP to be OCR1A.
2. The bits `WGM12` and `WGM13` belong to TCCR1B, not to TCCR1A.